# Moving the kafka streams state store to a new directory - what is the expected behaviour?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am looking for the expected behaviour of moving the state store of an existing streams applcation to a new location (via defining 'state.dir'). I could not find any documentation on this.

I thought that it should be transparent and it should be the same as when the streams application is stopped, the store is manually deleted and then the application is started again. In this case, the state store is retrieved from the corresponding internal changelog topic. But, when I changed the location (e.g. from /tmp/kafka-streams to anything else), I noticed that the state store was pushed downstream (to topic B). Is that expected? My stream is quite simple: from topic A -> aggregate(..) -> to topic B.

Thanks!

Comment: When you application is stopped it doesn't matter if your remove directory: `state.dir` or change the value of the property. Application should behave same - state store should be restored in your local directory. Are you seeing different behaviour?

Comment: Yes, in my case all messages of the store/ changelog topic are pushed downstream, meaning topic B receives all messages again.. I am using kafka-streams 2.0.1

Comment: Did the application "forget" the offset and reprocess old data from the input topic?

Comment: Nope it did not process (reconsume) messages from the input topic (i.e. topic A), I verified this as we log when we consume. But all messages were produced to the target topic (topic B). This is a reproducible behaviour, as I tried this two times with the same result.